# How to check a item in checkListBox and then output the checked box in the same checkListBox, but in Form2.cs

Tags: c#, checkbox, project, final, checklistbox

I have final school projects and this is one of my tasks.
So the project is about making an questionnaire.
I am struggling with the check box part,
I have to make 3 checkListBoxes with 4 options in them, 
but the problem is that when I click submit on the program, the program must open a Form2 app with the same 3 checkListBoxes but the answers that the user inputed must be checked in the Form2.
The only thing I know how to do is open Form2 from clicking the "Submit" button with 
`Form2 form2 = newForm2();
form2.ShowDialog();`

I only find solutions with a messageBox, so if anyone can help me I'll be very grateful.

Thank You for your time!

Comment: You should change constructor of newForm2 to accept checkbox values and in the constructor you should adding these values to checkboxes in the newForm2. And when you create `new newFrom2` in Form1 you should pass these values in constructor from the checkboxes of first form.

Answer (score 0):

To send your answers you have multiple options, you can do a list or send a string or an int. Since you seem to be using a CheckBoxList it seems like you want to pass all the checked boxes so the best thing to do is a List.

First you need to create the Form2 object and past the list of the selected items on each checkBoxList like this (I used a button in this case to open the second Form):

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //you create the list
            List<int> answers1 = new List<int>();
            //add each of the checked indices
            foreach (int index in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
                answers1.Add(index);
            //pass the parameter of the checked items to the other form
            new Form2(answers1).ShowDialog();
        }
```

and your Form2 needs to look like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
//You add the parameter of a list with the checked indices
        public Form2(List<int> answers1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
//here you check every index selected in your Form2 checklist
            foreach(int index in answers1)
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        }
    }
```

If you need to add more questions (aka Checklist) simply create add more checklist in the parameters on your Form2 and send them when you create it on Form1.

Pd. if you want to make the user only be able to select one option from your questions then I would recommend you use a GroupBox with RadioButtons instead of CheckedBoxList.